# Python logging create handlers in wrapper script for logger in imported module

Tags: python, logging, import

I am writing an API (python 2.7.x), and I have a worker script for it which does nothing on its own but can be wrapped by a variety of higher level scripts (ie one that feeds the worker data from csv, one from dB etc). The current task requires me to:

1. log INFO+ to console
2. log a certain set of INFO+ events to a .csv file
3. log ALL events to a distinct .log file

I've distilled my code to the following examples:

```
# SuperExample.py
import logging
import SubExample


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    verbose_log = 'debug.log'
    data_log = 'data.csv'
    format_string = '%(asctime)s::%(name)s::%(levelname)s::%(message)s'
    formatter = logging.Formatter(format_string)

    # verbose log is a typical event log used for debugging
    verbose = logging.FileHandler(verbose_log, mode='w')
    verbose.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    verbose.setFormatter(formatter)
    SubExample.logger.addHandler(verbose)

    # data log will eventually have a different formatter and a filter in
    # order to get a narrow set of events, formatted for post-processing ease
    data = logging.FileHandler(data_log, mode='w')
    data.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    data.setFormatter(formatter)
    SubExample.logger.addHandler(data)

    logging.info('Started')
    SubExample.do_something()
    logging.info('Finished')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and

```
# SubExample.py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def do_something():
    logger.debug('hey look I am doing something!')
    logger.debug('now I am doing something else!!')
    logger.info('this is my result!!!')
```

which gives me what I want in my files, but gives me this in my console:

```
INFO:root:Started
DEBUG:SubExample:hey look I am doing something!
DEBUG:SubExample:now I am doing something else!!
INFO:SubExample:this is my result!!!
INFO:root:Finished
```

I've read about the logging module and it's best practices, but very little of the example code works exactly the way its described when libraries get involved. So, my first question is: is this a basically sane approach? I haven't actually seen anyone else attach handlers to the subscript logger from the wrapper script, but it seems to do what I want.

And my second question is why do the DEBUG statements get into the console? I would think that `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` should prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

In the SuperExample.py file, I removed the basicConfig step and instead did this:

```
# SuperExample.py
import logging
import SubExample

def main():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(console)
    ...
    ...
    logger.info('Started')
    ...
    logger.info('Finished')
```

In the SubExample.py file:

```
# SubExample.py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(console)

def do_something():
    ....
```

Rest of the code is same as yours. When I run SuperExample.py, this is the output:

```
test_project ~$ python SuperExample.py
Started
this is my result!!!
Finished
```

The debug.log file has this:

```
2017-10-25 16:18:08,292::SubExample::DEBUG::hey look I am doing something!
2017-10-25 16:18:08,292::SubExample::DEBUG::now I am doing something else!!
2017-10-25 16:18:08,292::SubExample::INFO::this is my result!!!
```

The data.csv file has this:

```
2017-10-25 16:18:08,292::SubExample::INFO::this is my result!!!
```

So, it seems like the right way to do this is to add a `StreamHandler` to the logger in each of your modules and set it's level to what you want logged from there to the console. Also, whenever you do `logging.getLogger()`, you HAVE to set that logger's level to get the expected behavior from the handlers.

Comment: `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` in Sub isn't valid because that prevents debug messages from getting into the verbose log. And when I remove `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` and add the console logger per your second method, nothing gets logged at all.

Comment: Ok, I actually tried my suggestions out, and eventually arrived at something that might work for you. Editing my answer to reflect it.

Comment: When I run the edit I get 'this is a result twice' `DEBUG:SubExample:hey look I am doing something!
DEBUG:SubExample:now I am doing something else!!
this is my result!!!
INFO:SubExample:this is my result!!!` and this also violates the basic convention of not putting handlers in an API, as laid out in [link]https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library

Comment: I've actually got it working in my library now, but I weirdly can't get it to translate into the example code. So, basically don't spend more time here on my behalf, if I can get the example working I'll post a solution. Thanks for the efforts.